# Dummy Objects Good or Bad

Tags: c#, json, networking

I am working on a project that communicates a lot of data with a server. This data is in a json format. We end up creating a lot of dummy objects to parse the json data. This leads to having a lot of classes that just contain class members. Is there a better way of doing things?

thanks

Comment: Can you please define "dummy object"? It is difficult to teach you a better way without having any code to look at. I am also not sure what you mean by "better". Do you mean more readable or more performant or both or something else entirely? What do you think is wrong with having a class with a lot of members? So long as the members are properties (i.e. the class is a POCO DTO) it is pretty normal.

Comment: What are you using to serialize/deserialize the JSON?  JSON.net?  `JavaScriptSerializer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using NewtonSoft's JSON parser or something similar, you have a couple of choices here.  The usual use case here is to deserialize to a named type, thus:

```
var parsedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(content.AsString());
```

If you have many types for each differnet JSON message type you wish to receive and wish to avoid to, you can do the following:

```
var parsedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content.AsString());
```

This will give you a dynamic object that you can inspect and should also work given other Json libraries.  Alternatively, NetwtonSoft also provides the following method:

```
public static T DeserializeAnonymousType<T>(string value, T anonymousTypeObject);
```

This will allow you to deserialize to an anonymously typed object rather than a dynamic object.